# Textfield on Flutter dialog gives overflow on background

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm having a problem using a `textfield` inside a `dialog`. When I click it, the keyboard and menu goes up and overflow my background. I could put a `SingleChildScollView` for that, but I want to keep proportional (I'm using Spacer with flex property to do that) distance between elements, so the scroll would break it.

Is there another way to stop the background overflow?

Below is my Code:

code for background

```
return Scaffold(
  body: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0),
    child: Column(
      children: [
        .
        . widgets with some spacers here
        .
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

code for dialog

```
showDialog(
context: context,
builder: (context) => StatefulBuilder(
  builder: (context, setState) {
    return SimpleDialog(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),
      ),
      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30.0, 15.0, 30.0, 15.0),
      children: [
        .
        . widgets here
        .
      ],
    );
  },
),
```

);

Images:

[image: This is before clicking the textfield]

[image: this is right after I click the textfield]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,` under `return Scaffold`

```
return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,   //new line
      body: Padding(
      ...
      ...
```

Comment: This, coupled with setting resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false on my PersistentTabView (plugin) solved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

just try this solution in the Main Page

```
Scaffold(
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0),
    child: Column(
      children: [
       
    ],
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: I just said I don't want to use singlechildscrollview on main page